# Certain vanishing of Hom in the derived category of a finite dimensional algebra

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra and ${\rm D}(A)$ be the derived category of $A$. Let a fixed finitely generated $A$-module $N$ have the following property: for every complex ${\bf X}$ of finitely generated $A$-modules, $Hom_{{\rm D}(A)}(N, {\bf X}[t])=0$  for all integers $t$ implies that ${\bf X}$ is acyclic; here $[\quad]$ is just the shift in ${\rm D}(A)$. Now let ${\bf Y}$ be a complex of arbitrary $A$-modules. Is it generally true that $Hom_{{\rm D}(A)}(N, {\bf Y}[t])=0$ for every $t$ implies acyclicity of ${\bf Y}$?

I tried to use the fact that every complex of $A$-modules is a direct limit of a direct system of bounded complexes of finitely generated $A$-modules, but I can not complete the argument. Maybe there are other approaches of which I'm not currently aware. For example, I guess this should also follow from the fact that ${\rm D}(A)$ is generated, as a triangulated category, by bounded complexes of finitely generated $A$-modules. This means that the localising subcategory of ${\rm D}(A)$ generated by bounded complexes of finitely generated $A$-modules (i.e the smallest coproduct-closed triangulated subcategory of ${\rm D}(A)$ that contains bounded complexes of finitely generated modules) is the whole of ${\rm D}(A)$.

One more thing is that, if necessary, I can add some extra hypothesis on $N$. Any comment or suitable reference is appreciated.

Comment: Is N finitely generated

Comment: Yes, it is finitely generated.